# How to do binary operations on numbers and return result with a command like `\bitwiseXor{1}{2}`

Tags: math-operators, latex3, pgfmath

I have been trying to find a way to do `\bitwiseXor{1,2}` or `\bitwiseXor{1}{2}` and have it return 3.

- I tried to use pgfmath without much success (This is being used within the context of a TikZ auto-generated diagram)
- I also tried the `bitset` package without a lot of success.
- I tried using `pythontex` but it requires a more convoluted compilation. Since I am sharing this file, I would **prefer** if compilation is a one step process.
- And finally, I see that @egreg answered something similar [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416459), so it can be done, but I can't understand latex3 and how can I take everything out to just have the operations that returns just the decimal (or binary) number.

Thanks

Comment: It is very hard to answer this because you just say you tried to do something without success, but do not really show what you have tried. You can easily convert `bitset` macros to `pgf` functions, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/538866/194703). You can also declare your own pgf functions, pgf has built in functions for converting from and to binaries. I am sure one can answer your question within pgf or pgf + bitset but this needs a bit more details from your side. I do not want to have to look up the functions from the bitset manual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a fully expandable implementation of the bitwise XOR.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\bitwiseXor}{mm}
 {
  \recuenco_bitwise_xor:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \recuenco_bitwise_xor:nn
 {
  \int_from_bin:e
   {
    \__recuenco_bitwise_xor:ee { \int_to_bin:n { #1 } } { \int_to_bin:n { #2 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_bin:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \__recuenco_bitwise_xor:nn
 {
  \__recuenco_bitwise_xor_binary:ee
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn
     {
      \int_max:nn { \tl_count:n { #1 } } { \tl_count:n { #2 } } - \tl_count:n { #1 }
     }
     { 0 }
     #1
   }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn
     {
      \int_max:nn { \tl_count:n { #1 } } { \tl_count:n { #2 } } - \tl_count:n { #2 }
     }
     { 0 }
     #2
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__recuenco_bitwise_xor:nn { ee }

\cs_new:Nn \__recuenco_bitwise_xor_binary:nn
 {
  \__recuenco_bitwise_xor_binary:w #1;#2;
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__recuenco_bitwise_xor_binary:nn { ee }

\cs_new:Npn \__recuenco_bitwise_xor_binary:w #1#2;#3#4;
 {
  \int_abs:n { #1-#3 }
  \tl_if_empty:nF { #2 } { \__recuenco_bitwise_xor_binary:w #2;#4; }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\bitwiseXor{93}{208}

\end{document}
```

First the input is converted to binary. Then the two numbers are equalized in length by padding with the appropriate number of zeros the shorter one.

Then a recursive macro is called that outputs the XOR of each bit, by computing the absolute value of the difference.

The result is converted to decimal form.

You can check that the output is 141.

---

An extension to also cover AND and OR.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\bitwiseAnd}{mm}
 {
  \recuenco_bitwise:nnN { #1 } { #2 } \__recuenco_bitwise_and_binary:w
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\bitwiseOr}{mm}
 {
  \recuenco_bitwise:nnN { #1 } { #2 } \__recuenco_bitwise_or_binary:w
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\bitwiseXor}{mm}
 {
  \recuenco_bitwise:nnN { #1 } { #2 } \__recuenco_bitwise_xor_binary:w
 }

\cs_new:Nn \recuenco_bitwise:nnN
 {
  \int_from_bin:e
   {
    \__recuenco_bitwise:eeN { \int_to_bin:n { #1 } } { \int_to_bin:n { #2 } } #3
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_bin:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \__recuenco_bitwise:nnN
 {
  \__recuenco_bitwise_binary:eeN
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn
     {
      \int_max:nn { \tl_count:n { #1 } } { \tl_count:n { #2 } } - \tl_count:n { #1 }
     }
     { 0 }
     #1
   }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn
     {
      \int_max:nn { \tl_count:n { #1 } } { \tl_count:n { #2 } } - \tl_count:n { #2 }
     }
     { 0 }
     #2
   }
   #3
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__recuenco_bitwise:nnN { ee }

\cs_new:Nn \__recuenco_bitwise_binary:nnN
 {
  #3 #1;#2;
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__recuenco_bitwise_binary:nnN { ee }

\cs_new:Npn \__recuenco_bitwise_and_binary:w #1#2;#3#4;
 {
  \int_eval:n { #1*#3 }
  \tl_if_empty:nF { #2 } { \__recuenco_bitwise_and_binary:w #2;#4; }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__recuenco_bitwise_or_binary:w #1#2;#3#4;
 {
  \int_max:nn { #1 } { #3 }
  \tl_if_empty:nF { #2 } { \__recuenco_bitwise_or_binary:w #2;#4; }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__recuenco_bitwise_xor_binary:w #1#2;#3#4;
 {
  \int_abs:n { #1-#3 }
  \tl_if_empty:nF { #2 } { \__recuenco_bitwise_xor_binary:w #2;#4; }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \bin #1 { \exp_args:Ne \int_to_bin:n { #1 } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$93\mathbin{\mathrm{AND}}208=\bitwiseAnd{93}{208}$\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{r}
\bin{93} \\
\bin{208} \\
\hline
\bin{\bitwiseAnd{93}{208}}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

$93\mathbin{\mathrm{OR}}208=\bitwiseOr{93}{208}$\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{r}
\bin{93} \\
\bin{208} \\
\hline
\bin{\bitwiseOr{93}{208}}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

$93\mathbin{\mathrm{XOR}}208=\bitwiseXor{93}{208}$
\begin{tabular}[t]{r}
\bin{93} \\
\bin{208} \\
\hline
\bin{\bitwiseXor{93}{208}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was searching for. latex3 seems a bit overwhelming many times.

Comment: @AlexRecuenco I also added AND and OR.

Answer (score 6):

The following produces a `3` result, using the `bitset` package.  The `Dec` in the macro names implies we are working in decimal notation.  Other notations are available in the package (https://ctan.org/pkg/bitset).

The `Set` and `Get` are for setting and retrieving data.  With the logical operators, such as `\bitsetXor`, the result is placed into the first argument.

The MWE performs 1 XOR 2 to get 3, which gets placed in the A register.  Then 3 AND 2 is performed to get a result of 2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bitset}
\begin{document}
\bitsetSetDec{A}{1}
\bitsetSetDec{B}{2}
\bitsetXor{A}{B} 
\bitsetGetDec{A}

\bitsetAnd{A}{B}
\bitsetGetDec{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to use LuaLaTeX, here's some good news: Lua5.3 (which is part of LuaTeX) features several bitwise operations. Excerpting from section 3.4.2 of Lua5.3's reference manual:

[image]

The only mildly tricky thing is to find a way to "smuggle" the TeX-special characters `~` to Lua. The easiest way I know of to do this is to load the `luacode` package and employ its `\luaexec` macro.

Of course, one can also create LaTeX macros that act as "wrappers" for the Lua bitwise operations. See the macro `\bitwiseXOR` below, which takes two arguments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' macro
%% Define a LaTeX "wrapper" macro:
\newcommand\bitwiseXOR[2]{\luaexec{tex.sprint((#1)~(#2))}}
\newcommand\bitwiseAND[2]{\luaexec{tex.sprint((#1)&(#2))}}
\newcommand\bitwiseOR[2]{\luaexec{tex.sprint((#1)|(#2))}}

\begin{document}
The output of \verb+\luaexec{tex.sprint(1~2)}+ is \luaexec{tex.sprint(1~2)}.

The output of \verb|\bitwiseXOR{2-1}{1+1}| is also \bitwiseXOR{2-1}{1+1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will see if anybody can show how to do this natively, wiyj either latex2 or latex3.

Comment: Also, could you add some examples on how to use latex macros inside the luaexec command?

Comment: @AlexRecuenco - Please see the updated answer, which sets up a LaTeX "wrapper" macro that takes two arguments.

Comment: @AlexRecuenco -- A general comment: The argument of `\luaexec` gets fully expanded by LaTeX *before* it is passed to the Lua side. Hence, if `\x` and `\y` are LaTeX macros that evaluate to integers, it's entirely ok to write `\bitwiseXOR{\x}{\y}` or -- if you prefer not to use the wrapper macro -- `\luaexec{tex.sprint(\x~\y)}`.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful, I must have had some bug when I was quickly testing it then.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pgf only solution. It only requires pgf and the parser module thereof. Everything is done by pgf functions that can be used and parsed as usual in pgf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgfmodule{parser}
\makeatletter
\pgfparserdef{prp}{initial}{the character 0}% 
{\global\advance\pgfutil@tempcnta by1\relax
\edef\pgf@bit@list{0,\pgf@bit@list}}%
\pgfparserdef{prp}{initial}{the character 1}% 
{\global\advance\pgfutil@tempcnta by1\relax
\edef\pgf@bit@list{1,\pgf@bit@list}}%
\pgfparserdef{prp}{initial}{the character ;}% 
{\pgfparserswitch{final}}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{bitand}{2}{\begingroup
\pgfutil@tempcnta0\relax
\edef\pgf@bit@list{}%
\pgfparserparse{prp}#1;%
\pgfutil@tempcntb\pgfutil@tempcnta
\edef\pgfutil@tmpa{\pgf@bit@list}%
\pgfutil@tempcnta0\relax
\edef\pgf@bit@list{}%
\pgfparserparse{prp}#2;%
\edef\pgfutil@tmpb{\pgf@bit@list}%
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta<\pgfutil@tempcntb\relax
\pgfutil@tempcntb\pgfutil@tempcnta
\fi
\pgfutil@tempcnta0\relax
\edef\pgfutil@tmpe{}%
\loop
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpc}{{\pgfutil@tmpa}[\pgfutil@tempcnta]}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpd}{{\pgfutil@tmpb}[\pgfutil@tempcnta]}%
\pgfmathparse{int(and(\pgfutil@tmpc,\pgfutil@tmpd))}%
\edef\pgfutil@tmpe{\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@tmpe}%
\advance\pgfutil@tempcnta1\relax
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta<\pgfutil@tempcntb
\repeat
\edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfutil@tmpe}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{bitor}{2}{\begingroup
\pgfutil@tempcnta0\relax
\edef\pgf@bit@list{}%
\pgfparserparse{prp}#1;%
\pgfutil@tempcntb\pgfutil@tempcnta
\edef\pgfutil@tmpf{\the\numexpr\pgfutil@tempcnta-1}%
\edef\pgfutil@tmpa{\pgf@bit@list}%
\pgfutil@tempcnta0\relax
\edef\pgf@bit@list{}%
\pgfparserparse{prp}#2;%
\edef\pgfutil@tmpb{\pgf@bit@list}%
\edef\pgfutil@tmpg{\the\numexpr\pgfutil@tempcnta-1}%
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta>\pgfutil@tempcntb\relax
\pgfutil@tempcntb\pgfutil@tempcnta
\fi
\pgfutil@tempcnta0\relax
\edef\pgfutil@tmpe{}%
\loop
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta>\pgfutil@tmpf
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpc}{0}%
\else
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpc}{{\pgfutil@tmpa}[\pgfutil@tempcnta]}%
\fi
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta>\pgfutil@tmpg
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpd}{0}%
\else
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpd}{{\pgfutil@tmpb}[\pgfutil@tempcnta]}%
\fi
\pgfmathparse{int(or(\pgfutil@tmpc,\pgfutil@tmpd))}%
\edef\pgfutil@tmpe{\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@tmpe}%
\advance\pgfutil@tempcnta1\relax
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta<\pgfutil@tempcntb
\repeat
\edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfutil@tmpe}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{bitxor}{2}{\begingroup
\pgfutil@tempcnta0\relax
\edef\pgf@bit@list{}%
\pgfparserparse{prp}#1;%
\pgfutil@tempcntb\pgfutil@tempcnta
\edef\pgfutil@tmpf{\the\numexpr\pgfutil@tempcnta-1}%
\edef\pgfutil@tmpa{\pgf@bit@list}%
\pgfutil@tempcnta0\relax
\edef\pgf@bit@list{}%
\pgfparserparse{prp}#2;%
\edef\pgfutil@tmpb{\pgf@bit@list}%
\edef\pgfutil@tmpg{\the\numexpr\pgfutil@tempcnta-1}%
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta>\pgfutil@tempcntb\relax
\pgfutil@tempcntb\pgfutil@tempcnta
\fi
\pgfutil@tempcnta0\relax
\edef\pgfutil@tmpe{}%
\loop
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta>\pgfutil@tmpf
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpc}{0}%
\else
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpc}{{\pgfutil@tmpa}[\pgfutil@tempcnta]}%
\fi
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta>\pgfutil@tmpg
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpd}{0}%
\else
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpd}{{\pgfutil@tmpb}[\pgfutil@tempcnta]}%
\fi
\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\pgfutil@tmpc+\pgfutil@tmpd,2))}%
\edef\pgfutil@tmpe{\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@tmpe}%
\advance\pgfutil@tempcnta1\relax
\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta<\pgfutil@tempcntb
\repeat
\edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfutil@tmpe}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{bitwiseAnd}{2}{\begingroup
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpa}{bin(#1)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpb}{bin(#2)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpc}{bitand("\pgfutil@tmpa","\pgfutil@tmpb")}%
\pgfmathparse{0b\pgfutil@tmpc}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{bitwiseOr}{2}{\begingroup
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpa}{bin(#1)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpb}{bin(#2)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpc}{bitor("\pgfutil@tmpa","\pgfutil@tmpb")}%
\pgfmathparse{0b\pgfutil@tmpc}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{bitwiseXor}{2}{\begingroup
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpa}{bin(#1)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpb}{bin(#2)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tmpc}{bitxor("\pgfutil@tmpa","\pgfutil@tmpb")}%
\pgfmathparse{0b\pgfutil@tmpc}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$1~\mbox{XOR}~2=\pgfmathparse{bitwiseXor(1,2)}\pgfmathresult$

$3~\mbox{AND}~5=\pgfmathparse{bitwiseAnd(3,5)}\pgfmathresult$

\medskip

\edef\bitA{0100110101}%
\edef\bitB{1010110010001}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bitAandB}{bitand("\bitA","\bitB")}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bitAorB}{bitor("\bitA","\bitB")}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bitAxorB}{bitxor("\bitA","\bitB")}%


\begin{tabular}{c}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
first bit sequence & \bitA \\
second bit sequence & \bitB \\
\hline
first AND second & \bitAandB \\
\end{tabular} \\[2em] 
\begin{tabular}{lr}
first bit sequence & \bitA \\
second bit sequence & \bitB \\
\hline
first OR second & \bitAorB \\
\end{tabular} \\[2em]
\begin{tabular}{lr}
first bit sequence & \bitA \\
second bit sequence & \bitB \\
\hline
first XOR second & \bitAxorB \\
\end{tabular} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. But it seems somewhat inscrutable. Do you think that is just my lack of experience with the pgf internals?

Comment: @AlexRecuenco The reason why this looks so complicated is that I tried to adapt the conventions of other pgf functions for the variables. It also does the things locally, i.e. does not overwrite macros you could have defined by accident. (To me personally this is still way easier to read than `expl3`, where there is no real manual in which one can look up things.)